# Hello, I want to unpack a list of comments (ICollection) and show comments using data binding in c#. How can I access every comment of the list?

Tags: c#, list, uwp

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <ListView x:Name="lstvActiveIssues" ItemClick="lstvActiveIssues_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Height="500">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Issue">
                    <StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Title:"   Width="130" FontSize="10"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" Margin="10 10 0 0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Customer Name:"  Width="130" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Customer.FirstName}" Margin="10 5 0 0"  />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Customer.LastName}" Margin="5 5 0 0"  />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>                            
                    </StackPanel>                        
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lstvActiveIssues}" >
            <TextBlock Text="Details of the selected Issue" />
            
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Title:" Width="130" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Customer Name:" Width="130" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Customer.FirstName}" />
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Comment:" Width="130" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comments}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>            
    </StackPanel>
```

> Issue class is here

```
public class Issue
{
    public Issue()
    {

    }

    public Issue(long id, long customerId, string title, string description, string status, DateTime created)
    {
        Id = id;
        CustomerId = customerId;
        Title = title;
        Description = description;
        Status = status;
        Created = created;
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

> textblock show just System.Collection.Generic.List'1[DataAccessLibrary.Models.Comment]
> How can I show every comment in the textblock.I want to unpack a list of comments (ICollection) and show comments using data binding in c#. How can I access every comment of the list?

Comment: you should loop through the `Comments` and use the one panel like a customer for each comment.

Comment: I think your ListView needs an ItemsSource attribute.

Comment: I have created a method that include a foreach loop. the loop gives every element from comments but how can i use the method in binding I mean : Text="{Binding Comments?Method}"

Comment: I agree with JH_Dev, the reason for your issue is that you are binding the ICollection Object directly to the Text Property of a textblock. You could try JH_Dev's solution.

Comment: Thank you I should test the both of alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are binding the ICollection Object directly to the Text Property of your Text Block.

If you just want to show the values in the text block directly, you could use a [Value Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter?view=winrt-19041) to convert your list of comments into a string which would display in your text block.
However, based on your question I don't think this is your desired result.

My advice would be to use another listview to show the comments rather than a text block.
So something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
<ListView x:Name="issueCommentsList" ItemSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Comments, ElementName=lstvActiveIssues}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Height="500">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Comment">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="10"/>                     
                </StackPanel>                        
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

As you can see the ItemSource of the listview would have a data binding to the Selected Items comments. This would then allow you to create a custom UI for your comments.

*I have just added a simple text block for the comment UI so you can change that accordingly*

Hope this helps, Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you JH_Dev

Comment: happy to help @HosseinHosseini could accept my answer